# Is it possible or worth it doing quests marked as red in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

It seems that the rewards for slightly higher level quests are for that level or that they're adjusted for the current level. Is there a way to get a slightly OP weapon or piece of gear by expertly dodging for a half hour?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Worth it? Up to you to decide, it's your time, and the ultimate goal is having fun. If you're having fun beating those nearly impossible fights, keep doing it. Not having fun? Wait until you reach proper level. Personally I had some fun in the beginning, but after failing some of those, it stopped being fun and I found that I got tons of other things to do anyway. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it's **not** worth it.

Even if it was true that the weapon is slightly more OP, there is no point torturing yourself with 30 minutes of dodging and doing few points of damage. *Why?*

- The weapon/armor you will receive will almost certainly be locked out until you get the level that the quest actually required, so you will end up carrying a huge piece of metal in your backpack/chest that you won't be able to use at all, and with stats that might be scaled for your current level.
- As I did some research, most sources say that weapons and armors do scale, but with crappy random rates, and you will never be sure what this 30 minutes of dodging will give you.

Why don't you want to fully enjoy what game has to offer and do other (non-red) side quests or proceed with main plot? And when you have higher level the previously-red-quest is going to be enjoyable too... So unless you are some kind of masochist or achiever, I would discourage such gameplay.

Comment: I ended up taking like 30-40 minutes to kill an earth golem in one of those random encounter places. Didn't get hit once. I'm a masochist like that, I enjoy a challenge and W3 highest difficulty isn't particularly challenging for me... this is the Dark Souls player speaking here.

You are absolutely correct though, I got a piece of loot scaled to my level that was much worse than the Emmentaler with 3 stun runes I already have on there giving it 21+3+3 percent stun.

Answer (score 2):

It is not worth it for the gear. However, you *might* get more XPs doing the quest. This might be a quicker way to level. Although, there are plenty of questions at your level which provide XPs aplenty so even that does not sound like a good reason to slug it out.

Comment: Battering through higher-level quests to level up quicker is a little self-defeating.  If you level up on Red quests, and your Green quests turn Gray, they'll only reward 1xp up on completion.

Comment: @Liesmith: I think we agree there...